# accessing parts of sub-queries to build HTML in a PHP server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that returns the count of active and inactive posts, plus the specific post details. Here's the query

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT propertyID, streetAddress, city FROM residence.property
WHERE residence.contact.contactEmailAddress1 ='$contactEmailAddress1' AND activePosting = '0') inactposts,
    (SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS 'inactiveCount') inact,
(SELECT DISTINCT propertyID, streetAddress, city FROM residence.property
INNER JOIN contact ON residence.contact.ContactID = residence.property.ContactID
WHERE residence.contact.contactEmailAddress1 ='$contactEmailAddress1' AND activePosting = '1') actposts,
    (SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS 'activeCount') act;")
or die('<li class=error>Ooops</li>'.mysql_error());
```

The query works in my web page. In MySQL Workbench it returns things looking like:

```
propID   address        city        inactCount  propID  address     city        actCount
366   110 Main Street   Perinton        1       352    3 Some Place Perinton        3
366   110 Main Street   Perinton        1       353    5 Joe Place  Perinton        3       
366   110 Main Street   Perinton        1       356    111 Main     Perinton        3
```

The issue for me is the 2 parts of the sub-query results don't have an identifier (that I can find), so in the HTML constructed by the PHP server, I can't separate the lists into into inactive posts (inactposts) and active posts (actposts). Currently the HTML **only** returns the list of active posts. I've tried putting "inactposts", the name of the temporary table, in various places and I just get error messages

Here's the PHP doing the HTML construction:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($fetch) ) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    $inactiveCount = $row["inactiveCount"];
    $activeCount = $row["activeCount"];
    $storedStreetAddress = $row["streetAddress"];
    $storedCity3 = $row['city3'];
    $error_NumberInactives = "<ul>You have $activeCount active posts and $inactiveCount inactive posts.</ul>";
    $error_List_Actives = "<li>Your $activeCount active posts are:</li>";
    $errorMessages[0] = $error_NumberInactives;
    $errorMessages[1] = $error_List_Actives;
    $errorMessages[] = "<li> $storedStreetAddress, $storedCity3 </li>";
}else{ //error message}
```

How can I construct separate lists of sub-query results from this query? Or do I need a different query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need another query without the aggregation if you want the individual rows.
Alternately, select all of the posts (with details) in one query and parse the result in php to count the number of active and inactive:

```
SELECT DISTINCT propertyID, streetAddress, city, activePosting FROM residence.property
INNER JOIN contact ON residence.contact.ContactID = residence.property.ContactID
WHERE residence.contact.contactEmailAddress1 ='$contactEmailAddress1'
```

p.s. I assume you have sanitized your inputs outside of the provided code, otherwise you need to do that.

Comment: The current query gets all the individual rows, and the HTML partially displays them, i.e. one group. Are you sure there is no way to assign the 2 groups in the query - for example, using AS or GROUP, or something in PHP that can recognize the 2 parts of the response? I've hit a wall, and don't know what to search on for answers, but it seems the problem can be solved with some labeling/naming. Then again, I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: I have succeeded in naming the 2 sub-queries by putting AS inactposts and AS actposts after the closing parentheses. The query works. Now I need some PHP that will recognize each of the 2 named groups of rows. . . . or something like that.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe since you string together multiple queries (each semicolon ends a query) within one php call you're only going to get the results of the final query (the active results). Put the query for 'inactive' into its own call `$fetch2` and run the while loop separately.

Comment: I did some more research and concluded 2 simple queries may be as fast or faster than one complex query, even if I could get it to work. I don't have performance data, but that can come later. Thanks for setting me off in the right direction, at least for the moment.